# Parsing Cisco System Logs with Regex

Tags: regex, splunk

I have three types of logs I would like to parse:

**Message #1:** Username entry (random@somewhere.org) with length (253) created for mobile aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa

**Expected Matches:**

- random@somewhere.org
- aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa

**Message #2:** Username entry (hello) is deleted for mobile aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa

**Expected Matches:**

- hello
- aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa

**Message #3** Guest user logged in with user account (randomnonexistentuser) MAC address aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa, IP address 127.0.0.1.

**Expected Matches:**

- randomnonexistentuser
- aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa
- 127.0.0.1

So far, I have this regex to identify the MAC addresses (labeled as mobile in two of the three examples): https://regex101.com/r/qFE95M/14

I also have this regex...

```
(?P<IP_address>[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})
```

...to find the IP address. However, I'm not sure how to make just that named group optional and tie it together with the MAC address piece.

Finally, I have this regex...

```
^[^\(\n]*\((?P<user_account>[^\)]+)\)
```

...to find the usernames (could be email addresses, single words, etc.). But again, I'm unsure how to tie it in with the other two named groups.

How do I reconcile these three matches together, so it finds them in the three messages above?

Comment: If the order of those three information is always going to be same, then you can use a single regex where you can make each part optional, otherwise it will be better to use separate regex for finding each of those information.

Comment: that's a good idea - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should give you everyting in a named group: https://regex101.com/r/qFE95M/15

Comment: thank you - this definitely works. do you have any suggestions to make it less reliant on the words preceding each item?

Comment: well, if you can give me some more example data, i can make the regex more reliable. The problem with the username in the brackets is, that there can be more brackets in a line. And what if somone logs in with username 253? So if you can give me more data, i can narrow down the regex to fit your needs.